# How to find all documents in objectdb flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, dart-pub

There is no documentation how to find all documents in objectdb flutter ?

Comment: a quick google search and I found this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/objectdb

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
final documents = db.find({});
```

That is `find()` method, but with empty map as a first argument. This `query` argument is a list of conditions that a document has to meet. When there is no conditions - every document meets them!